# C++ - SFML ошибка при компиляции: ‘Window’ does not name a type

Tags: c++, sfml

Есть 2 класса:

1) Window.hpp

2) Spaceship.hpp

Подключил Window.hpp к классу Spaceship.hpp а Spaceship.hpp подключил к Window.hpp

Window.hpp:

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Spaceship.hpp"
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Window{
public:
    Window(){
        settings.antialiasingLevel=8;
        window.create(sf::VideoMode(width, height), "Game", sf::Style::Close, settings);
        window.setPosition(sf::Vector2i(desktop_width/2-width/2, desktop_height/2-height/2));

        Background();
        Spaceship();

        while(window.isOpen()){
            while(window.pollEvent(event)){
                if(event.type==sf::Event::Closed)
                    window.close();
                if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Escape))
                    window.close();
            }

            window.clear();
            window.draw(background_sprite);
            window.draw(spaceship.ship_sprite);
            window.display();
        }
    }

private:
   void Background(){
        background_texture.loadFromFile("textures/background.png");
        background_sprite.setTexture(background_texture);
        background_sprite.setPosition(0, 0);
    }

public:
    const int width=500, height=900;
    const int desktop_width=sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode().width, desktop_height=sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode().height;

    Spaceship spaceship;

    sf::RenderWindow window;
    sf::Event event;
    sf::ContextSettings settings;

    sf::Texture background_texture;
    sf::Sprite background_sprite;
};
```

Spaceship.hpp:

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Window.hpp"
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Spaceship{
public:
    Spaceship(){
        Ship();
    }

    void Ship(){
        ship_texture.loadFromFile("textures/Ship.png");
        ship_sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0, 0, 48, 32));
        ship_sprite.setPosition(window.width/2-ship_sprite.getTextureRect().width/2, window.height-ship_sprite.getTextureRect().height);
    }

    Window window;

    sf::Texture ship_texture;
    sf::Sprite ship_sprite;
};
```

При компиляции выдаёт ощибку:

```
Spaceship.hpp:19:5: error: ‘Window’ does not name a type
19 |     Window window;
   |     ^~~~~~
In file included from Window.hpp:3,
             from Game.cpp:1:
Spaceship.hpp: In member function ‘void Spaceship::Ship()’:
Spaceship.hpp:16:33: error: ‘window’ was not declared in this scope
16 |         ship_sprite.setPosition(window.width/2-ship_sprite.getTextureRect().width/2,   window.height-ship_sprite.getTextureRect().height);
   |                                 ^~~~~~
make: *** [makefile:2: output] Error 1
```

Кто может подсказать как исправить?

Comment: Понять, что именно неверно в вашем коде, и исправить ошибку. Вы *всерьез* рассчитываете, что без вашего кода кто-то будет придумывать, что вы там понаписали?! Что означает "подключили"? Идите сюда - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help - и читайте, как задавать вопросы!!!

Comment: Что так сразу плохая оценка?

Comment: Компилирую window.hpp

Comment: Конструктор `Window` вызывает конструктор `Spaceship`, который вызывает конструктор `Window`, который...

Comment: Ну и как это исправить?

Comment: `using namespace std;` в хедере — это сильно.

Comment: компилировать хедер Вас не смущает, вызовы конструкторов - нет. а какой то безобидный using namespace std - смущает

Comment: Поставьте нормальную оценку ёпты ; )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас классическая циклическая зависимость. Когда создается один из классов, ему нужно знать размер второго. Но второму нужно знать размер первого. Как это решать?

Вариант первый. В одном из мест сделать указатель плюс `forward declaration` - то есть, просто написать перед объявлением класса краткое объявление другого - `class Window;` или `class Spaceship;`. Указатель конечно потребует вызова new/delete или использование `unique_ptr`.

В конструкторе Window есть такой вызов `Spaceship();` - Вы просто вызываете конструктор корабля, создаете временный объект, который тут же удаляется... Это точно не то, что Вам нужно.

Но давайте посмотрим на это по другому. Класс корабля знает имеет свою переменную для window. Но оно ему нужно только что бы размеры посчитать. Так может передать эти размеры? Перепишем

```cpp
class Spaceship{
public:
    Spaceship(){

    }

    void Ship(int width, int height){
        ship_texture.loadFromFile("textures/Ship.png");
        ship_sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0, 0, 48, 32));
        ship_sprite.setPosition(width/2-ship_sprite.getTextureRect().width/2, height-ship_sprite.getTextureRect().height);
    }


    sf::Texture ship_texture;
    sf::Sprite ship_sprite;
};
```

И теперь вызываем правильно - передав параметры.

И вместо

```cpp
Background();
Spaceship();
```

пишем

```cpp
Background();
spaceship.Ship(window.width(), window.height());
```

Все, осталось удалить лишний инклуд.

И ещё почитать о том, что такое конструкторы и классы.

Comment: Так вызов Spaceship(); так и должен работать

Comment: по моему - будет.

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало